# Rational Question for $a + b$ and Irrationality of $a^2 + b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have looked into the question and need help. Find some $a,b$ ${\in}$ $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a + b$ ${\in}$ $\mathbb{Q}$, $a^2 + b^2 \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\frac{a}{2} < b < a$.  Or prove no such $a$ and $b$ exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $a = 10 + \pi $ and $b = 10 - \pi $?

Comment: ... where $\pi$ can be replaced with any irrational (except square roots of a rational) between $0$ and $\frac{10}3$ ...

Comment: That works great.  Thank you.

Comment: How about if $a^3 +b^3$ is also irrational with the same conditions above?  Does there exist such $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Then $10 + \pi $ and $10 - \pi $  also work

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok.  One more.  What about $a^4 + b^4$ with the same conditions as above?  Is there such an $a$ and $b$?

Comment: These work for $a^n + b^n $ irrational for any $n \geq 2$. Use the binomial expansion to see it

Comment: @Hagen von Elitzen any transcendental number would work right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, any transcendal number instead of $\pi$ would work

Answer (score 0):

let $a=r+ir$ and $b=r-ir$, $r$ is a rational number and $ir$ is irrational , $a^2+b^2$ will be irrational if $ir^2$ is irrational 
now if the question was other way around , i.e $a+b$ irrational $a^2+b^2$ cannot be rational , that's also wrong as we can take both of them as square roots of an integer